# how to stop keyboard cursor to move to starting point

Tags: flutter, dart

like i have an edit profile page and inside text form field i populate textform field with existing data but when i press on that textform field i want my cursor to start from the last index of my pre loaded data but the keyboard cursor moves to starting point is there a way to achieve this.

this is my text form field

```
TextFormField(
                            decoration:
                                const InputDecoration(hintText: "First Name"),
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                return "Please enter your first name";
                              } else {
                                return null;
                              }
                            },
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              firstName = firstNameController.text;
                              if (firstName.isNotEmpty) {
                                firstName =
                                    "${firstName[0].toUpperCase()}${firstName.substring(1)}";
                                firstNameController.selection =
                                    TextSelection.fromPosition(
                                        TextPosition(offset: firstName.length));
                              }
                            },
                            controller: firstNameController..text = firstName,
                          ),
```

i am able to populate data inside textform field but the problem is when i press on textformfield i want my keyboard starting point to be at the last index of this populated data but keyboard cursor moves to the starting point no matter what need some help here thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selection like this

```dart
firstNameController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                          TextPosition(
                              offset: firstNameController.text.length));
```

Comment: no its not working when keyboard appear for the first time the cursor moves to the starting point

Comment: Add the same code in onTap of the textField too

Comment: added on on tap as u mentioned above code but still the cursor moves to initial position

Comment: Have you assigned the controller to the textfield as _textEditingController? And also set the name in initstate.

Comment: ahh yes thanks it worked when i initialized first